# Perform function after form validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I am using react, typescript, and Email JS library. I am using the react-hook-form library and yup to validate forms.

I have worked out the validation and sending the email, but I am unable to do both these functions together. When a user submits the form, I want the "sendEmail" function to be called if the "handleSubmit(onSubmit)" function which validates the form is successful.

The form's 'onSubmit' property needs to be changed so that both of these can be called.
Currently I can call these individually with 'onSubmit={sendEmail}' or 'onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}' and they will work.

What I tried was to put the expression 'handleSubmit(onSubmit)' inside the sendEmail function but validation did not work then.

I have also used react-hook-form library.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { string, number, object, InferType } from "yup";
import { url } from "inspector";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

function onSubmit(values: Props) {}

type Props = InferType<typeof schema>;

const schema = object({
  firstName: string().required("First name is required"),
  lastName: string().required("Last name is required"),
});

function FormEmail() {
  const form = useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | undefined>();

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Props>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const sendEmail = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
       'YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current!, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY'
      )
      .then(
        (result: { text: any }) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error: { text: any }) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };

return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={form}>

            <h3>First Name</h3>
            <input
              id="firstName"
              type="text"
              {...register("firstName")}
            />
            <span className="error">{errors?.firstName?.message}</span>

            <h3>Last Name</h3>
            <input
              id="lastName"
              type="text"
              {...register("lastName")}
            />
            <span className="error">{errors?.lastName?.message}</span>

            <button className="" type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormEmail;
```

Comment: does `handleSubmit(onSubmit)` return a boolean?

Comment: No it does not return a boolean. I think I have to catch the error somehow. I've edited the 'sendEmail' function in my question to reflect the suggestion of an answer to this post by @Arkellys. I am unsure how to catch the error though.  [docs for handleSubmit](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit/#main) .This is the documentation. I'd really appreciate any help you can provide! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [in the doc](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit/#main), if you want to call `onSumbit` remotely you need to write it like this:

```
handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked!  I've edited  'sendEmail' function and  added 'handleSubmit(onSubmit)();' to it. But do you know how I can prevent the code from going forward if there is a validation error? I looked at the docs but haven't exactly understood how I can catch errors if I invoke it remotely.

Comment: @Travis I'm glad it worked. From what I read on the doc, you just need to pass the event to `handleSumbit` and then add a catch: `handleSubmit(onSubmit)(e).catch(() => { ... })`. Or you can follow the second example with `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add `handleSubmit(onSubmit)(e).catch(() => { ... })` to the `sendEmail` function. But the `e` parameter was giving an error which was: Argument of type '{ preventDefault: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any>'.
  Type '{ preventDefault: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any>': nativeEvent, currentTarget, target, bubbles, and 10 more.ts(2345). Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: I also tried the try/catch way. I didn't get an error but it didn't work correctly. I will edit the question to add this code if we can't find the error for the first method. Thanks for the help man

Comment: @Travis The subject of this question seems to be resolved, you should mark it as such and ask a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: @Travis and the `.catch(() => { ... })` have to be on `handleSubmit`, not `sendEmail`.

Comment: Thanks, I put the `.catch(() => { ... })` on `handleSubmit` but its still not working as intended.  I have created a new question at this link: [new question link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73361186/how-to-catch-react-hook-form-validation-error) . Please do check it out