# How to catch react hook form validation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hook-form

I am using react, typescript, and Email JS library. I am using the react-hook-form library and yup to validate forms.

I need to catch the form validation errors that are thrown by the react-hook-library and only if there are no errors, an email should be sent with Email JS.

The relevant part of the code is the `sendEmail` function.

The `handleSubmit(onSubmit)();` which is in the `sendEmail` function validates the form.
[docs for handleSubmit]https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit/#main

I put `handleSubmit(onSubmit)()` in a try catch block but it is not catching the errors. The code continues and the email is sent. How can I stop the email from being sent, if there is a form validation error.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { string, number, object, InferType } from "yup";
import { url } from "inspector";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

function onSubmit(values: Props) {}

type Props = InferType<typeof schema>;

const schema = object({
  firstName: string().required("First name is required"),
  lastName: string().required("Last name is required"),
});

function FormEmail() {
  const form = useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | undefined>();

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Props>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const sendEmail = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
      emailjs
        .sendForm(
          "service_ztay5wh",
          "template_wcc4f29",
          form.current!,
          "aXbWTWKdwzgImlYqz"
        )
        .then(
          (result: { text: any }) => {
            console.log(result.text);
          },
          (error: { text: any }) => {
            console.log(error.text);
          }
        );
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  };

return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={sendEmail} ref={form}>

            <h3>First Name</h3>
            <input
              id="firstName"
              type="text"
              {...register("firstName")}
            />
            <span className="error">{errors?.firstName?.message}</span>

            <h3>Last Name</h3>
            <input
              id="lastName"
              type="text"
              {...register("lastName")}
            />
            <span className="error">{errors?.lastName?.message}</span>

            <button className="" type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormEmail;
```

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have changed my former answer.

> I need to catch the form validation errors that are thrown by the react-hook-library and only if there are no errors, an email should be sent with Email JS.

As I know, react-hook-form does not throw error, but set the error state. So you can use the error state or isValid flag to prevent sending a email in your submit function. And about the ts error in your comment, just have a look at this [api doc](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit)

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<Props>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

const sendEmail = handleSubmit((_, e) => {
    e?.preventDefault();
    try {
      onSubmit();
      if (isValid) {
          // send email
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // only catch error thrown by emailjs
      return;
    }
  });

return (
    <form onSubmit={sendEmail} ref={form}>
    ...
)
```

or

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<Props>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

const sendEmail = () => {
    try {
      onSubmit();
      if (isValid) {
          // send email
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // only catch error thrown by emailjs
      return;
    }
  };

return (
    <form ref={form}>
    ...
       <button className="" onClick={sendEmail}>
          Submit
       </button>
    </form>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still getting an error: TS2345: Argument of type '(e: {    preventDefault: () => void;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubmitHandler<AssertsShape<{ firstName: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; lastName: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; ... 4 more ...; enquiryDetails: StringSchema<...>; }>>'.

Comment: This is the continuation of the error cause it didn't fit in the previous comment: Types of parameters 'e' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Property 'preventDefault' is missing in type 'AssertsShape<{ firstName: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; lastName: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; ... 4 more ...; enquiryDetails: StringSchema<...>; }>' but required in type '{ preventDefault: () => void; }'.

Comment: Welcome! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @leonoheart Thank you so much for telling me about isValid. I think it might solve my problem, however I am still facing an issue with it, that isValid is always false. I looked this up and found a stack overflow question where the solution was to add something like mode: "onChange". I changed the code to this.`useForm<Props>({
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });`. However, isValid is still always false, I opened a new question here: [new question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422064/form-isvalid-is-always-false) Please do help if you can!

Comment: @leonoheart Hey have you had the chance to check this out, would really appreciate it!