# form 'isValid' is always false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react, typescript, and Email JS library. I am using the react-hook-form library and yup to validate forms.

I am using `isValid` from the react-hook-form library to see if the form is successfully validated, and then I can perform some function.

But `isValid` is always coming as false. I saw that this was an issue for others too, and the solution was to add `mode: "onChange"`. However, `isValid' is still always false.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { string, number, object, InferType } from "yup";
import { url } from "inspector";

function onSubmit(values: Props) {}

type Props = InferType<typeof schema>;

const schema = object({
  firstName: string().required("First name is required"),
});

function FormEmail() {
  const form = useRef(null);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<Props>({
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const onSubmit = () => {};

  const sendEmail = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(onSubmit)();

    try {
      if (isValid) {   
      // execute a function
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // catch error 
      return;
    }
  };


return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={form}>
            <h3>First Name</h3>
            <input
              id="firstName"
              type="text"
              {...register("firstName")}
            />
            <span className="error">{errors?.firstName?.message}</span>

            <button type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormEmail;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: isValid is not used in your code anywhere just in if statement. Ofcourse it is always falsy?

Comment: @Taras Sorry I forgot to put it here, just edited it in, `formState: { errors, isValid }`

Comment: try to set `defaultValues` and log `errors` obj

Comment: @Mike I tried setting defaultValues but I am still facing the same error

Comment: not sure, try to check working example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-validationschema-rm35t?file=/src/index.js